# Egit missing compare with HEAD option when committing

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

When trying to commit changes to git from eclipse, I often want to look, what exactly changed in the file. For some reason egit doesn't give me that option. [image: egit commit staged changes]

It only offers to compare with working tree, which makes no sense to me, since it will show no differences.

For example TortoiseGit has the option compare with base. But it is inconvinient to use external tool for making commit. Is there any solution with egit for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double clicking on the file should open the compare view between the central repository version and local work space version of that file. Hope that helps you

Comment: Yeah, thank you, such a simple idea didn't come to my mind!